# jquery problem identify appended anchor

Tags: jquery

I've a problem to get the id of dynamically loaded anchor appended to a div.  Here is the code that I get after filling the div:

```
<div id="sotto_eti">
    <a href="#" id="a">a</a> <a href="#" id="b">b</a> <a href="#" id="c">c</a>
</div>
```

and here is the script:

```
<script>
$("#sotto_eti a").click(function()
{
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
</script>
```

Thanks in advance for your help

ciao h.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you would retrieve the ID of a links added dynamically, you should use the live function instead :

```
<script>
$("#sotto_eti a").live("click", function()
{
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can [use `.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) to handle dynamically loaded elements:

```
$("#sotto_eti a").live('click', function() {
    alert( this.id );
});
```

Or better, [use `.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) which is similar to `.live()`, but more efficient.

```
$(function() {
    $("#sotto_eti").delegate('a', 'click', function() {
        alert( this.id );
    });
});
```

Comment: `more efficient` do you have any source for that?

Comment: @Rakesh - Simply based on the fact that they do the same thing, but `.delegate()` is localized. When you do `.live()`, jQuery needs to test *every* click on the page that bubbles up to the root against the `"#sotto_eti a"` selector. With `.delegate()`, only clicks *inside* the `"#sotto_eti"` container need to be tested against the `"a"` selector. Also, because there can be only one `#sotto_eti` on the page, there's only *one* handler in both cases, so there's no extra overhead with jQuery managing multiple handlers.

Answer (score 0):

```
    alert($(this).get(0).id);
```

should work.

Comment: This doesn't really fix the issue. Using `$(this).attr("id")` is correct. Your version wraps `this` with jQuery, then immediately removes it and accesses the `id` property. So it would make *much* more sense to do `this.id`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method for dynamic elements:

```
$("#sotto_eti a").live('click', function()
{
  alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

[Here is working demo](http://jsbin.com/agigu3)

Also make sure that you include the jquery library in your page.

Comment: No need to wrap your code with `.ready()` if you're using `.live()`. http://jsbin.com/agigu3/2/ :o)

Comment: I've not write but I already use ready handler but it does not works :(

Answer (score 0):

Use [live()](http://added) for elements added later: